org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 25S03
Facing intermittent behavior of database connection failure in production environment. We get warning of SQLState: 25S03 in my production environment followed by the the specific below error:
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-36068) (conn=16217550) Communications link failure .connection timeout.

ERROR [com.mkpt.rest.exceptionmappers.EJBExceptionMapper] (default task-36068) Handling EJBException with 500 response.: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet

I didn't try anything, it seems that is the timeout issue of server, if not responded in specific time frame decided by server. we would be working on it but i will appreciate if anyone can help on it till the time.
